# SQLite Interop DLL Missing Method - Windows Mobile CF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sqlite, windows-mobile

In my Windows Mobile project, I have added the `SQLite.Interop.066.DLL`, set the [**Build Action**] = [*Content*] and set the [**Copy to Output Directory**] = [*Copy if newer*].

Still, *after* I open my my connection, I receive the unhandled `Missing Method Exception` message "**Can't find PInvoke DLL 'SQLite.Interop.DLL**" whenever I attempt to execute the reader on the `SQLiteCommand`.

What is wrong?

[image: code]

[image: solution]

Comment: Why .066.dll and not just .dlll?

Comment: From the help: ***System.Data.SQLite.DLL** and **SQLite.Interop.XXX.DLL** must be deployed on the Compact Framework.  The XXX is the build number of the System.Data.SQLite library (e.g. "059").  SQLite.Interop.XXX is a fully native assembly compiled for the ARM processor, and System.Data.SQLite is the fully-managed Compact Framework assembly.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, `SQLite` is not being managed very well.

This was a bug someone reported over a year ago (3 May 2010) in the SQLite [setup.exe download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/SQLite-1.0.66.0-setup.exe/download). To get working DLLs, I had to [download the binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/SQLite-1.0.66.0-binaries.zip/download).

I had seen it earlier, but dismissed it because it was so old. Today, I downloaded the binaries and installed them in my project - **No errors!**

Here is the link for others:

[Version 1.0.66.0 - bad build for Compact Framework ?](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2334/10829.aspx)

Note to the `SQLite` community: **Update your code, please!**

Comment: Thanks a lot, jp2code! you really made my day! I was pulling off my hair for 2-3 days! I couldn't think about that would be a dll bug! After I have downloaded your suggested dlls, it worked like a charm! I appreacite your answeer a lot! Thanks again! :)

Comment: LOL, no problem @MuzzyB. I'm glad someone got use out of my findings.