# Windows Mobile 6.1 + SQLite: Could not load type "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection"

Tags: sqlite, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I'm having toubles with SQLite library.
I have to add some functionality to one legacy project (and therefor I need SQLite DB).

I've tried https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.94.0/sqlite-netFx35-binary-PocketPC-ARM-2008-1.0.94.0.zip, but anytime when debugger tries to get into function which contains SQLite calls (SQLiteConnection, SQLiteCommand) I get error:

Could not load type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection' from assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.94.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1FDB50B1B62B4C84'.

File **System.Data.SQLite.dll** is added to References by standard way.

File **SQLite.Interop.094.dll** is added to root of the project and is set to BuildAction: Content and Copy to output..: Copy if newer.

Target device: **Windows Mobile 6.1**

Visual Studio 2005

Target platform: Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks good. So you have the two Sqlite-DLLs in your application-path? But, you are running Visual Studio 2005, so I guess you only have CompactFramework 2.5. Can you use Sqlite in the version for compact framework 3.5? If yes, please check if you have installed CF3.5 on your device (\Windows\cgautil.exe)

Comment: Actualy, I forgot data cable today, so I'm trying to run it on a emulator (Windows Mobile 6 Professional VGA Emulator) and I can't find out what version of CF is installed on it.
Tomorrow I'll try it on device (there's CF3.5 installed) and let you know.
Thanks for a good suggestion.

Comment: You just have to start "wceload.exe" from your \Windows\-Directory. There your installed versions of compact framework are shown. On sqlite.org they tell that CF3.5 is required, but what I did not find out if you have to use it with an CF3.5-Application or if you can use it with a CF2.5-Application as well.

Comment: To get version of installed CF on device you must start \Windows\CGACUTIL.exe on the device not wceload (is the cab installer app).

Comment: That's true, there's not file like wceload.exe, but I've found **cgacutil.exe**.
On Emulator, there's just .NET CF FW v 2.0.7045.0, but on my device there's also 3.5.7283.0. 
So now I'm able to get inside method where are SQLite classes used. I thought that CF 3.5 is installed also on emulator, but it's not true.

Comment: Ohh damn sorry, I mixed it up. Sure you are right it is cgautil *D'OH*

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Version 1.0.94 is NOT working properly. I fails on SQLiteConnection.Open() (Method not found.... or Mising method...).

Please use version 1.0.66. Solution found at [SQLite Interop DLL Missing Method - Windows Mobile CF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067793/sqlite-interop-dll-missing-method-windows-mobile-cf)